# How can I simulate cloth between one static object and one moving object?

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I'm trying to replicate stretchy canvas between two ribs for an architecture project, and I need to animate the movement of one of the ribs - so the canvas would stretch as it moves. I've tried pinning vertex groups in the cloth sim but it either a) only moves the edge vertices, or b) moves the entire group.

I basically just want one rib moving, one rib static, and the cloth sim between them.

Here's the effect I want to achieve (from Rhino 6), but with cloth sim panels instead:

[image]

Here's the problems I'm running into in Blender:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

- Create your sail and a create a bone that you call *Bone1*:

[image]

- Give your sail a vertex group that will be the cloth pin (call this group *Pin*), it must be all around the border:

[image]

- Give your sail a vertex group for the bone control (call this group *Bone1*) that must have a decreasing influence:

[image]

- Give your sail a *Cloth* physic simulation. In the *Cloth panel > Shape*, choose the group you've created as *Pin Group*, enable *Self Collisions*. Select the vail, shift select the bone, switch it to *Pose* mode, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Set Parent To > Armature Deform* so that the bone will control the vertex group that has its name. Create the rest of the object, give it *Collision* physic if it is supposed to interact with the vail:

[image]